# HTML video looks different on different machines

Tags: html5-video

I have mp4 video files. I want to show them on website with HTML `<video>` tag. But they look different on different machines.

I have an machine with XP Pro SP3, Chrome 49, it displays videos with shadows. And other machines don't appear to have this problem.

I've tried:

On problem machine:

- Use native video player to play exact same video, no problem
- Update video driver of problem machine to latest, problem still exists
- Use Firefox, but Firefox complains not support this format of video
- Disable some Chrome flags I think maybe relate to video (`disable-accelerated-video-decode`, `disable-cast-streaming-hw-encoding`), doesn't work. I even tried disable all experimental features of Chrome, problem still exists.

On virtual machines (virtual machines are not installed on problem machine, but on my other PC, because my problem PC only has 2GB memory):

- On virtual machine with Win7, Chrome 44, no problem
- On virtual machine XP Pro SP3, Chrome 44, no problem

Does anyone know why this happens, and how to fix it? Suggestions are also welcomed. I'm running out of ideas...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know currently, this is limited issue of Chrome 47-49 on XP.

I checked the Chrome change log, seems nothing related to video. No clue why this happens, and not sure how to fix it.